# .empty() in jquery, empty child only from its parent

Tags: jquery, css, parent, children

when i use $("child").remove() or $("child").empty(), it will remove all child element from the page, i want it only remove the child element from the one parent element.
there are many more parent class on this page, so is there anyway i can remove the content only from the parent when user click on button class.. the button_parent class in same level with the parent class

```
<div class ="button_parent"><div class ="button"></div></div>
    <div class = "parent">

        <div class= "child"></div>
        <div class= "child"></div>
        <div class= "child"></div>
        <div class= "child"></div> 
    </div>
<div class ="button_parent"><div class ="button"></div></div>
    <div class = "parent">
        <div class ="button"></div>
        <div class= "child"></div>
        <div class= "child"></div>
        <div class= "child"></div>
        <div class= "child"></div> 
    </div>
<div class ="button_parent"><div class ="button"></div></div>
    <div class = "parent">
        <div class ="button"></div>
        <div class= "child"></div>
        <div class= "child"></div>
        <div class= "child"></div>
        <div class= "child"></div> 
    </div>
<div class ="button_parent"><div class ="button"></div></div>    
    <div class = "parent">
        <div class ="button"></div>
        <div class= "child"></div>
        <div class= "child"></div>
        <div class= "child"></div>
        <div class= "child"></div> 
    </div>
<div class ="button_parent"><div class ="button"></div></div>
    <div class = "parent">
        <div class ="button"></div>
        <div class= "child"></div>
        <div class= "child"></div>
        <div class= "child"></div>
        <div class= "child"></div> 
    </div>
<div class ="button_parent"><div class ="button"></div></div>    
    <div class = "parent">
        <div class ="button"></div>
        <div class= "child"></div>
        <div class= "child"></div>
        <div class= "child"></div>
        <div class= "child"></div> 
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

`.remove()` removes the element, but `.empty` just removes the content. Anyways.. You need to remove the `child` div using the `parent` as context

```
$('.parent').click(function () {
   $(this).find('.child').remove();
});
```

**For HTML:**

```
<div class ="button_parent"><div class ="button"></div></div>
<div class = "parent">

    <div class= "child"></div>
    <div class= "child"></div>
    <div class= "child"></div>
    <div class= "child"></div> 
</div>
```

You can do

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    $(this).parent() //this will be .button_parent
           .next()   //next node is .parent
           .find('child')  //find all child in .parent 
           .remove()       //remove them
});
```

You can use `.empty()` of `.child` divs are the only divs exist inside `.parent`

Comment: Could just do `$('.child', this).remove();`

Comment: what if i want to click the button class inside parents to remove the content. the child and button are in the same level

Comment: You can do `$(this).parent().find('.child').remove()`

Comment: A potential risk with this is,it will still become generic and it will allow you to do this operation on any division that currently clicked?Is that what the he wants?

Comment: @sayannayas Yes, I believe that is what he wants.. (_is there anyway i can remove the content only from the parent when user click_) Incase if he want to remove specific child, then he could have wrote a handler for `.child` click and do a `$(this).remove()` on `child`

Comment: Then this should be the correct answer.May i know why this got down voted?

Comment: what happen if the button class in a separate class, .button_parent.

Comment: @sayannayas Well, no idea.. everyone got a downvote.. its an anonymous downvote.. just ignore it.

Comment: @will.i.am Post the relevant HTML including the button.. and so we can see and update our answers.

Comment: just change the html a little bit,

Comment: does the .parent() will only go back one level, what happen if i need to go back to level above?? should it be .parent().parent()??

Comment: @will.i.am Do the level you want to go back has a class, then you can use `.closest()`. You should read http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Answer (score -1):

Its better to use id instead of css selectors in that case

give a definite id to the div you want to maintain this operation.You can keep your classess intact and only apply id to the div you want the operation to happen

```
<div class = "parent" id="operation">
    <div class= "child"></div>
    <div class= "child"></div>
    <div class= "child"></div>
    <div class= "child"></div> 
</div>
```